# Refresh TableView in ParallaxBlur Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, parallax

I am using this library in my project:

https://github.com/pyro2927/ParallaxBlur

I am using the JPBParallaxTableViewController class, and I am wondering if it is possible to insert a pull to refresh action instead of zooming in on the image when the tableview is being pulled down.

Comment: Pavel's answer is correct, Your needs and ParallaxBlur are in conflict.

Answer (score 2):

It is seems like impossible to do this in simple way. Because Parallax Table View Controller inherits from Parallax View Controller and just aggregate TableView.
Also it is become harder because Parallax View Controller overrides scrollViewDidScroll:

So, there is no simple way to add refresh action. You need rewrite large amount of code.